# Three.js/Webgl vertex.y does not update

Tags: three.js, webgl, shader, vertex-shader

In effort to learn vertex/fragment shaders I decided to create a simple rain effect by updating the y position of a point in the vertex shader and resetting it back to animate through again using Three.js PointCloud. I got it to animate across the screen once but gets stuck after resetting the y position.

```
uniform float size;
uniform float delta;

varying float vOpacity;
varying float vTexture;
void main() {
    vOpacity = opacity;
    vTexture = texture;
    gl_PointSize = 164.0;       
    vec3 p = position;
    vec3 p = position;

    p.y -= delta * 50.0;
    vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(1.0 * p, 1.0 );
    vec4 nPos = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;

    if(nPos.y < -200.0){
        nPos.y = 100.0;
    }
    gl_Position = nPos;
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: create a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Or [post it inline](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) which is arguably better than a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

shader does not change the vertex position permanently

that means

```
gl_Position = nPos;
```

will not propagate to your position attribute in geometry

shader only runs on graphics card and has no access to memory of the browser

you can change your code to this:

```
nPos.y = mod(nPos.y, 300.0) - 200.0;
```

now the y coordinate should change as you want it to(going from 100 to -200 then back to 100)